# How to load different global css styles for different environments with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components

I would like to load different global css styles for different environments.
In angular-cli.json it is "hardcoded" to  "styles.css". Is there a way to load different css file - based on some property defined in environment?

Answer (score 9):

Based on **user1964629**'s answer I came up with the following solution

I have a white label web-app that I wanted to apply a different themes to based on which client it was for.

First I made two different apps in the **angular-cli-json** file. I basically duplicated the one that was there and added an name property to each one:

```
"apps": [{
  "name": "client1",
  ...
},
{
  "name": "client2",
  ...
}]
```

---

#### Client specific SCSS

In the app directory I created a folder named `scss` and added some files and subdirectories like so:

[image]

As you can see there is a client specific folder for each client containing a `_theme.scss` file. This file has client specific scss variables.There are also some general `.scss` files in the root of the `scss` directory.

I then added this to the **client 1** app in **angular-cli.json**:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
       "scss/client.client1",
       "scss"
    ]
  },
```

and this to **client 2**:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
       "scss/client.client2",
       "scss"
    ]
  },
```

Adding the `includePaths` meant I could import `scss` files without specifiying the full path to the file, and at the same time only load the theme file relevant to the client. I changed my `styles.scss` to look like this:

```
@import 'theme';  // <--- this would be different based on which client app is running.
@import 'global'; // <--- this would be the same for both apps
```

It also meant I could `@import 'theme'` into any other `.scss` file in my project to access theme specific variables.

---

#### Client specific environments

I went a little further from here and created client specific environment files too. Like this:

[image]

I updated the **angular-cli.json** for **client 1** like this:

```
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.client1.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.client1.prod.ts"
  }
```

And for **client 2** like this:

```
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.client2.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.client2.prod.ts"
  }
```

Then added a 'client' property for each environment. This allowed me to make decisions in my scripts based on which client app was running. This is, for instance, what the `environment.client1.prod.ts` file looks like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  client: 'client1'
};
```

---

#### Finally running everything

I could then run both client apps at the same time client like so:

```
ng serve --app client1 --port 4201
ng serve --app client2 --port 4202
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest there could be a way to do so by passing in a string of the environment from the environment.ts file into the app component and then you could load a specific environment component which has the CSS listed in its styles array? But I'm not sure if this is 'best practice'?

Here's a link explaining the process of passing a string to a component from the environment files: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/amp/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately  this doesn't help. I am familiar how to use environment variables inside my components, but in this case I would need to use environment variable in "higher level", since I want to change global styles, not component specific styles. If angular-cli.json would allow usage of environment variables, solution would be easy, but it doesn't AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah I get you wanted to use a 'global' style so what I was trying to say was that you could wrap each "version of application" within a global component which has these specific styles?

Comment: I see what you mean, maybe I could just wrap everything inside one div in app component.
That was my first thought  but this solution doesn't fit best since I need to style page body tag. (css provided by client)
If I don't find the another way I guess I 'll have to use root component styling instead of page body styling. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4685
There is no way to achieve this with environments. But You can do this by creating multiple apps in angular-cli.json with different "styles" property.

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "app1",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
      "styles-app1.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
},
{
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles-app2.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
```

And then run ng with --app option e.g. ng build --prod --aot --app app1

Answer (score 0):

You can add as may **css** file globally you want for your project
you just need to add it in styles in `angular-cli.json` file like this:

```
 "styles": [ 
        "listing.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

create `listing.css` file and it will be available globally same as `styles.css`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Shailesh, but this is not what I want. I want to switch between different styles depending on environment, not just use all of them at the same time.