# How to let users change theme for Angular app?

Tags: css, angular, sass, themes, runtime

I want to add a couple of themes on my Angular app and I would like to let users to do it by theirselft.

I just want to make some changes to colours, so this should affect just few rows of my SCSS files:

**styles.scss**

```
html, body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**app/app.component.scss**

```
.title {
    color: green;
}

.subtitle {
    color: grey;
}

.text {
    color: white;
}
```

How to make it changeable by the user at runtime?

I searched and searched on Google and even here on SO (for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439172/how-to-load-different-global-css-styles-for-different-environments-with-angular)), but all the answers deal with loading different style files at compile time, but this could not let users to change the theme when the app is running.

Comment: I think this one explains what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441036/switch-themes-in-angular-material-5. So just using classes that will make your theme "switch".

Comment: This article may help you : https://dev.to/adamaso/angular-6-dynamic-themes-without-a-library-2e9c

Comment: @JeroenE I'm not using Material so your solution is not applicable in my case.

Comment: @Zooly It's me that I create themes, users should only select the one they like. So I will create for example 2 themes and user will be able to switch from one to another.