# Angular use SCSS based on condition

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

I want to know that is there any way to load and unload SCSS dynamically.
The problem is I have two scss named style1.scss and style2.scss. I currently referred style1.scss in my angular.json file. Now I want to load only the style 2.css for a particular module and not style1.scss. Is there any way to achieve this like using conditions in angular.json file or anywhere to load or unload the scss file.

Comment: Are these styles depending on the module at all or do they depend on a certain component? And could you show us what you've already got in your `angular.json` and which version you're exactly using?

Comment: "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
And the angular version am using is 7

Comment: refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439172/how-to-load-different-global-css-styles-for-different-environments-with-angular?noredirect=1&lq=1