# Pass custom option while building the angular application

Tags: angular

I have currently three files, say a1, a2, a3 in a folder. I want to include one of the file in the build, depending on the option provided on **ng build** command. My question is, how can I pass custom variable along with build command and also get the variable in the angular.json

Comment: `environment` files are made for that, but you will never be able to use their values in a json file unless you use a build tool.

Comment: Is there any option to provide a custom variable while running the *ng build* command?

Comment: Instead of being cryptic, could you please explain your end goal ?

Comment: I have to replace the CSS file for different build. CSS for each build lies in seperate folder. I want to pass the folder name while creating the build. I don't want to create separate configuration for each one.

Comment: Okay, then please see [already answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439172/how-to-load-different-global-css-styles-for-different-environments-with-angular) about that. If it doesn't answer, please let me know so that I can re-open your issue.

Comment: Its entirely different. I want to replace the html and CSS for components with the file in corresponding folder in angular.For each build there will be different folder

Comment: Well if you want to replace all files of your application for different build, just make two applications ... And still, the other question is about that. So how is that different ?

Comment: Not all, only the html and CSS files. There may be 10 different styles and HTML format. I don't think creating separate appliacation will be a good option

Comment: So you didn't bother to read the other question. The **only solution** available is to create two applications. Please, take a look again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193089/discussion-between-cr7-and-trichetriche).